# Piwik. Where are the CSS styles set?

Tags: css, task-parallel-library, matomo

Does anyone know how the CSS is set in Piwik. I've been going through their CSS files in Themes/CSS, and for the life of me, can't find where they set the widgetTop class, even with Firebug.

I'd appreciate if anyone could shed some lights on their CSS styling, since the current interface while pleasant is quite heavy and we have limited server bandwidth. Also, the top bosses wanted something that looks like our corporate color (yes, blue and orange).

It's hosted externally, which limits my Notepad++ fu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in

```
plugins/Dashboard/templates/dashboard.css
```

but the effective serving is handled in a pretty nifty way, the url I see is

```
http://demo.piwik.org/index.php?module=Proxy&action=getCss&cb=f0a5d3cb58ea3268483e289e9a322ccb
```

which via Proxy.php will lead you back to the AssetManager (who will handle getCss), who combines the different pieces of css and js it finds into one request for performance reasons.

But don't forget the site uses Smarty, so you may have to work a bit on the tpl files as well as on the css files if you want tto change look 'n feel.

Comment: Thanks, fvu. Our piwik now looks orange.

Comment: Actually i have the needs now , but on matomo, i need to add some <div> to add banner and add text into the navigation <nav>, couldnt find fom where i start in dashboard.less under plugins/Dashboard/stylesheets